# BLED112 set Encryption?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth

I'm using BLED112 and "pygatt BGAPI backend" Python library to communicate to a custom 3rd party BLE device.

Using the "Bluegiga BLE GUI" I can read/write to the device characteristic but only after clicking the "Encrypt" button next to the device.

What is the python library equivalent to setting / enabling the encryption?

I can't seem to find encryption parameter in either adapter initialization or in the device connection functions

Simplified code:

```
import pygatt
adapter = pygatt.BGAPIBackend()
adapter.start()
device = adapter.connect("01:23:45:67:89", address_type=pygatt.BLEAddressType.random, timeout=10)
raw_read = device.char_read_handle(32)
```

Answer (score 0):

The library has a function "bond" which performs the same command as the "Encrypt" button.

```
import pygatt
adapter = pygatt.BGAPIBackend()
adapter.start()
device = adapter.connect("01:23:45:67:89", address_type=pygatt.BLEAddressType.random, timeout=10)
device.bond()
raw_read = device.char_read_handle(32)
```